# mongoDB concatenate results

Tags: mongodb

Whats the best way to concatenate results in MongoDB? In particular the PHP driver? Do I need to use mapReduce?

In mySQL I would do something like this: SELECT CONCAT(fname,' ',lname) as name FROM users but I can't seem to find a simple way to do this in mongo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### In the PHP Driver

I recommend doing this in your application. Use PHP's concatenation features to add a "fullname" attribute/key to the user object/array. I'd stay away from map/reduce/finalize unless you need to do some database-side processing or selecting before returning the results. (And, before that, maybe look into `where` queries as well - http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries.)

### In the Shell

If this is a one-off query and you're doing it in the shell, there are two different (but related) ways to go about this.

Which one you use depends widely on if *only* want the concat-ed name or if you want the rest of the document to go with it. For instance, if you only want the name, you can do something like this:

```
> db.show_concat.find().forEach( function (o) { print(o.fname + ' ' + o.lname); } )
john smith
jane doe
```

Otherwise, if you want the other fields, you can do:

```
> db.show_concat.find().forEach( function (o) { o.full_name = o.fname + ' ' + o.lname; printjson(o); } )
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4cd6dabb5391d08d405bb0bb"),
        "fname" : "john",
        "lname" : "smith",
        "full_name" : "john smith"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4cd6daee5391d08d405bb0bc"),
        "fname" : "jane",
        "lname" : "doe",
        "full_name" : "jane doe"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use aggregate, $project and $concat :
https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/

It would be something like this  :

```
db.show_concat.aggregate(
   [
      { $project: { full_name: { $concat: [ "$fname", " - ", "$lname" ] } } }
   ]
)
```