# MongoDB: concatinate multiple number values to string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document (inside aggregation, after `$group` stage) which have an object (but I could form array, if I needed it to) with `number` values.

[MongoPlayground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7JHzcJnWn_P) with data and my aggregate query available here.

And I want to make a new `_id` field during next `$project` stage, consisted of this three `number` values, like:

```
   item_id | unix time | pointer
_id: 453435-41464556645@1829
```

The problem is, that when I am trying to use [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/), the query returns me an error like:

```
$concat only supports strings, not int
```

So here is my question: is it possible to achieve such results? I have seen the relevant question [MongoDB concatenate strings from two fields into a third field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820253/mongodb-concatenate-strings-from-two-fields-into-a-third-field), but it didn't cover my case.

Comment: You `$concat` only support string, you need to convert your fields value to string using `$toString` check https://mongoplayground.net/p/SSlXW4gIs_X

Comment: @turivishal that is great, thank you so much! Could you form it as an answer? So I can accept it and mark as solved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/index.html) only concatenate strings, these fields `$_id.item_id` contains int value and `$_id.last_modified` double value,

The [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/index.html) converts a value to a string,

```
_id: {
  $concat: [
    {
      $toString: "$_id.item_id"
    },
    " - ",
    {
      $toString: "$_id.last_modified"
    }
  ]
}
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/SSlXW4gIs_X